# Linker error and how to access members

Tags: c++, class, linker, linker-errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

class B;

class A {
    int x;
public:
    B it();
    friend class B;
};

class B {
    int y;
    A a;
public:
    B(A aa):y(99), a(aa) {};
    int get_y() {
    return this -> y;
    }
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    A md;
    cout << md.it().get_y() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Ignore encapsulation and other details, my problem is that I want to use "md.it().get_y()", but my compiler gives me this linker error: 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::it()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: You cannot use class B when it is not fully defined, when compiler reaches the definition of A, it has no idea what class B is like. It just knows that there is a class called B, so it cannot create an object of B to return it! The solution is to either use reference or a pointer to object

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: After realizing that

```
B it();
```

is NOT a function returning B, but an object inside class A:
You have a cyclic depenency, where A uses B and B uses A. The compiler is unable to resolve this.
Forward declares like

```
class N;
```

ONLY work for pointers or references, where the actual object size does not have to be known

EDIT: I just realized I misread the error message.
You are missing the function definition for the it() method.

The forward declare propably does not work for

```
B it();
```

changing the code to

```
B& it();
```

should fix your issue

Note that B is now returned by refernce instead of by value. So you might actually do something like

```
const B& it() const;
```

Comment: I changed the code according to your explanations, but still does not work

Comment: Can you post the source for the it() function?

Comment: it() isn't a function. It is a B object. I used "()" for constructor

Comment: Remove the () and it should work. Just tested, does not work, you have a cyclic dependency which you need to resolve

Comment: So I have to use derivation ?

Comment: A possible solution would be, to change the "it" member into a pointer, and create it inside the A constructor.